# DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: vb.net

I have a `DataGridViewButton` and I would like to hide or remove the text of a button when a condition is true. Is it possible, or anyone have any workaround to get to it.

Comment: Hide or remove the text? You want a button with no text??

Comment: Are you using win forms or asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the button text to a space by setting that cell's value to a space.

```
DataGridView1.Rows(rowNum).Cells(colNum).Value = " "
```